# how to change months in this drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i am using following code to make day month year selection using drop down my days are changing according to month like if February than 28 day and if march than 31 but in my month drop down it shows only January 12 time . i am not getting error this is my code..

```
 private int Day
{
    get
    {
        if (Request.Form[ddlDay.UniqueID] != null)
        {
            return int.Parse(Request.Form[ddlDay.UniqueID]);
        }
        else
        {
            return int.Parse(ddlDay.SelectedItem.Value);
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.PopulateDay();
        ddlDay.ClearSelection();
        ddlDay.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}
private int Month
{
    get
    {
        return int.Parse(ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Value);
    }
    set
    {
        this.PopulateMonth();
        ddlMonth.ClearSelection();
        ddlMonth.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}
private int Year
{
    get
    {
        return int.Parse(ddlYear.SelectedItem.Value);
    }
    set
    {
        this.PopulateYear();
        ddlYear.ClearSelection();
        ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString()).Selected = true;
    }
}

public DateTime SelectedDate
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(this.Month + "/" + this.Day + "/" + this.Year);
        }
        catch
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        if (!value.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
        {
            this.Year = value.Year;
            this.Month = value.Month;
            this.Day = value.Day;
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (this.SelectedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            this.PopulateYear();
            this.PopulateMonth();
            this.PopulateDay();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Request.Form[ddlDay.UniqueID] != null)
        {
            this.PopulateDay();
            ddlDay.ClearSelection();
            ddlDay.Items.FindByValue(Request.Form[ddlDay.UniqueID]).Selected = true;
        }
    }
}

private void PopulateDay()
{
    ddlDay.Items.Clear();
    ListItem lt = new ListItem();
    lt.Text = "DD";
    lt.Value = "0";
    ddlDay.Items.Add(lt);
    int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(this.Year, this.Month);
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        lt = new ListItem();
        lt.Text = i.ToString();
        lt.Value = i.ToString();
        ddlDay.Items.Add(lt);
    }
    ddlDay.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()).Selected = true;
}

private void PopulateMonth()
{
    ddlMonth.Items.Clear();
    ListItem lt = new ListItem();
    lt.Text = "MM";
    lt.Value = "0";
    ddlMonth.Items.Add(lt);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        lt = new ListItem();
        lt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(i.ToString() + "/1/1900").ToString("MM");
        lt.Value = i.ToString();
        ddlMonth.Items.Add(lt);

    }
    ddlMonth.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()).Selected = true;
}

private void PopulateYear()
{
    ddlYear.Items.Clear();
    ListItem lt = new ListItem();
    lt.Text = "YYYY";
    lt.Value = "0";
    ddlYear.Items.Add(lt);
    for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i >= 1950; i--)
    {
        lt = new ListItem();
        lt.Text = i.ToString();
        lt.Value = i.ToString();
        ddlYear.Items.Add(lt);
    }
    ddlYear.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the first one which you pass as `i` using loop is considered as **Day** not Month, Better way is to use `DateTime` constructor's [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes **year,month,day** as input, instead of Converting `string` to `Date` this way:

```
lt.Text = new DateTime(1900,i,1).ToString("MM");
```